# Issue on Processing Array Items Into a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

can you please take a look at this code and let me know why I am not able to add the array Items into the .box? I already used the .text() and .html()

```
    var letters = [];
    var str = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z";
    var letters = str.split(",");
    for (var j = 0; j <letters.length; j++) {
        $(".box").html(letters[j]);
     }
```

but they only add the last item "Z" into the box

Comment: You want to add the letters one after the other? With time inbetween?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.append()` because `.html()` will replace the whole html everytime

Comment: Hi Anton, thanks for reply but that is exactly what I want to do. I want to add each item to box and replace it by next item not to append all to there

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using `.html()` which replaces any pre-existing text with the new text.

Use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead:

```
 $(".box").append(letters[j]);
```

Comment: Hi Zee and thanks for reply but that is exactly what I want do do. I want to add each item to box and replace it by next item not to append all to there

Comment: I can't understand what you're saying.

Comment: just loop into the array and Add all items to the box One by One

Comment: Still doesn't make sense, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

That's because [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2)  doesn't append but replaces the content.

A solution could be to use `append` instead of `html` but that's slow if you have a big array. In such a case, the best practice is to build the HTML in one go :

```
$(".box").html(letters.join(''));
```

If what you want is to have a delay between the box being changed, you can use `setTimeout` :

```
(function step(){
  var letter = letters.shift();
  if (!letter) return;
  $('.box').html(letter)
  setTimeout(step,200);
})()
```

Comment: @dystory, thanks for reply but I do not want to add all items to the box. what I want to do is adding them one by one and replacing the existing with new in the list

Comment: @user3649067 You mean with a delay ?

Comment: I guess , I am not sure about that but what I would like to do is displaying all letters in the box one by one and after each other

Answer (score 1):

.html() will replace the content at the each iteration of loop. In first iteration 'A' will be placed into (".box") and int second iteration 'B' will be replaced by 'A' and so on. When loop ends the last letter 'Z' will be the only content in ('.box'). if youy want to add all letters in ('.box') use .append()

see link : http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

You will need a delay in updating the box in order to show the letters one after the other:

```
var str = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z";
var letters = str.split(",");
next();

function next() {
    if( letters && letters.length) {
     $(".box").text(letters.shift());
     window.setTimeout(next, 500);
    }
}
```